# Is it possible to define a generic type Vector in Actionsctipt 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, vector, generics

Hi i need to make a VectorIterator, so i need to accept a Vector with any type. I am currently trying to define the type as * like so:

```
var collection:Vector.<*> = new Vector<*>()
```

But the compiler is complaining that the type "is not a compile time constant". i know a bug exists with the Vector class where the error reporting, reports the wrong type as missing, for example:

```
var collection:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>()
```

if Sprite was not imported, the compiler would complain that it cannot find the Vector class. I wonder if this is related?

Comment: That's a great question. Uncharted territory!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it looks like the answer is there is no way to implicitly cast a Vector of a type to valid super type. It must be performed explicitly with the global Vector.<> function.

So my *actual* problem was a mix of problems :)

It is correct to use Vector. as a generic reference to another Vector, but, it cannot be performed like this:

```
var spriteList:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>()
var genericList:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>()
genericList = spriteList // this will cause a type casting error
```

The assignment should be performed using the global Vector() function/cast like so:

```
var spriteList:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>()
var genericList:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>()
genericList = Vector.<Object>(spriteList)
```

It was a simple case of me not reading the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/package.html#Vector()).

Below is some test code, I would expect the Vector. to cast implicitly to Vector.<*>.

```
public class VectorTest extends Sprite
{
    public function VectorTest()
    {
        // works, due to <*> being strictly the same type as the collection in VectorContainer
        var collection:Vector.<*> = new Vector.<String>() 

        // compiler complains about implicit conversion of <String> to <*>
        var collection:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>()
        collection.push("One")
        collection.push("Two")
        collection.push("Three")

        for each (var eachNumber:String in collection)
        {
            trace("eachNumber: " + eachNumber)
        }

        var vectorContainer:VectorContainer = new VectorContainer(collection)

        while(vectorContainer.hasNext())
        {
            trace(vectorContainer.next) 
        }
    }
}

public class VectorContainer
{
    private var _collection:Vector.<*>

    private var _index:int = 0

    public function VectorContainer(collection:Vector.<*>)
    {
        _collection = collection
    }

    public function hasNext():Boolean
    {
        return _index < _collection.length
    }

    public function get next():*
    {
        return _collection[_index++]
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the iterator constructor 

VectorIterator(collection:Vector.<Object>)

and here is how the creation looks:

var spriteList:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>()
var iterator:VectorIterator = new VectorIterator(Vector.<Object>(spriteList)) 

pretty ugly :)

Comment: Does this mean there's no way to retain the typing? I.e. have a VectorIterator.<Sprite> or VectorIterator.<Vector.<Sprite>>...

Comment: yep, as far as I know. Generics are not a part of the ECMA language spec, so there is no way for me to define a class with a generic type. I can use the Vector class, but that is more of a compiler level hack as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Brian - Vectors are supported natively by the AVM. I've not looked at how they are defined but how they are referenced is definitely unique. See my self-answered question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553445/how-do-generics-vector-work-inside-the-avm

Comment: Thanks Richard, it's interesting to see how Vectors were implemented, hopefully Generics will become part of the language soon, along with a decent Proxy system for as3mock, make mocking a hell of a lot easier for you :D

Comment: @Brian - asmock actually already supports dynamic mocking (which would explain research into the AVM) - you can check it out at asmock.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

```
[Bindable]
public var selectedItems:Vector.<Category>;

public function selectionChange(items:Vector.<Object>):void
{
    selectedItems = Vector.<Category>(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can refer to an untyped Vector by just calling it `Vector` (no `.<>`)

Comment: That is illegal syntax according to the compiler. it at least expects Vector.<*>()

Answer (score 0):

With Apache Flex 4.11.0, you can already do what you want. It might have been there since 4.9.0, but I have not tried that before.

Answer (score -1):

```
var collection:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>()
```

maybe?
But i'm just speculating, haven't tried it.

Comment: This causes a type casting error. If i create a Vector.<Sprite> and pass it to my Iterator, the compiler complains about casting a Vector.<String> to a Vector.<Object>.

Comment: Just a hunch - try declaring the method as accepting a Vector (with no type parameters)

Comment: That is illegal syntax according to the compiler. it at least expects Vector.<*>()

Answer (score -3):

```
var collection:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>()
```

but only on targeting flash player 10 cs4

Comment: This causes a type casting error. If i create a Vector.<Sprite> and pass it to my Iterator, the compiler complains about casting a Vector.<String> to a Vector.<Object>