# Dynamically instantiate a typed Vector from function argument?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, dynamic, vector, constructor

For a game I'm attempting to develop, I am writing a resource pool class in order to recycle objects without calling the "new" operator. I would like to be able to specify the size of the pool, and I would like it to be strongly typed.

Because of these considerations, I think that a Vector would be my best choice. However, as Vector is a final class, I can't extend it. So, I figured I'd use composition instead of inheritance, in this case.

The problem I'm seeing is this - I want to instantiate the class with two arguments: size and class type, and I'm not sure how to pass a type as an argument.

Here's what I tried:

```
public final class ObjPool
{
    private var objects:Vector.<*>;

    public function ObjPool(poolsize:uint, type:Class)
    {
        objects = new Vector.<type>(poolsize);  // line 15
    }
}
```

And here's the error I receive from FlashDevelop when I try to build:

> \src\ObjPool.as(15): col: 18 Error: Access of undefined property type.

Does anybody know of a way to do this? It looks like the Flash compiler doesn't like to accept variable names within the Vector bracket notation. (I tried changing constructor parameter "type" to String as a test, with no results; I also tried putting a getQualifiedClassName in there, and that didn't work either. Untyping the objects var was fruitless as well.) Additionally, I'm not even sure if type "Class" is the right way to do this - does anybody know?

Thanks!

Edit: For clarification, I am calling my class like this:

```
var i:ObjPool = new ObjPool(5000, int);
```

The intention is to specify a size and a type.

Double Edit: For anyone who stumbles upon this question looking for an answer, please research [Generics in the Java programming language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html). As of the time of this writing, they are not implemented in Actionscript 3. Good luck.

Comment: Good luck. I suspect it is not possible (since Vector.<> is an exceptional case, and ActionScript doesn't *really* support generics or templates).

Comment: As a workaround, you can pass Vector.<YourType> into object pool constructor at compile time.

Comment: @alxx Y'know - I actually hadn't thought about that. That solution doesn't abstract everything away as nicely, and because AS3 passes by reference, it leaves an opening for references to a private variable outside of the class. It's not really as controlled as I would like it to be, but I might consider it if a linked list doesn't meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question (+1!), mostly because I've never tried it before. It seems like from your example it is not possible, which I do find odd, probably something to do with how the compiler works. I question why you would want to do this though. The performance benefit of a Vector over an Array is mostly the result of it being typed, however you are explicitly declaring its type as undefined, which means you've lost the performance gain. So why not just use an array instead? Just food for though.

**EDIT**

I can confirm this is not possible, its an open bug. See here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3748 Sorry for the news!

Tyler.

Comment: No - that's not the intention. I want to type the vector, and I want to give it a fixed length, but I want to choose the vector *type* dynamically through my class, so that I can create a pool that holds only one type of object (of my choosing when I instantiate that class). By doing this I'll be reaping all of the benefits of a vector - fixed length iteration and type-checking. If I can get it to work, that is.

Comment: Is a variable of type Class the right way to do this? I want to pass a type as an argument through that veriable and use it to instantiate my Vector, but I've never actually done this before. I wanted to avoid using strings if possible, as that would necessitate the full package name for any instance. [For clarification, I'm calling my class like this: "var i:ObjPool = new ObjPool(5000, int);".]

Comment: Ouch! That sucks, but at least it wasn't something I was doing. I read the comments in that link, though, and I do understand the compile-time complications, since Vectors use contiguous memory (as far as I understand). It's a real shame, as having this feature would open up a lot of possibilities, but I guess I'll have to find another way - a linked list would probably work best, perhaps. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a bug anymore.  In Flash CS6, I can run this code: `import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName; var c:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("__AS3__.vec::Vector.<int>") as Class; var v:Vector.<int> = new c(); v.push( 6 ); trace( v[0] );` and it traces "6" as expected.  All that's necessary for this to work is that the Vector.<int> exist in the AppDomain, which means you must declare the type at least once somewhere.

Comment: I'm currently using this feature in a JSON library I created that embeds type information, so it can read back strongly-typed vectors from a JSON object.  Typically these vectors are members of existing types, so the specific vector type is compiled into the code and available for dynamic instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to do this for a while now and Dominic Tancredi's post made me think that even if you can't go :

```
objects = new Vector.<classType>(poolsize);
```

You could go something like :

```
public final class ObjPool
{
    private var objects:Vector.<*>;

    public function ObjPool(poolsize:uint, type:Class)
    {
        var className   : String = getQualifiedClassName(type);
        var vectorClass : Class  = Class(getDefinitionByName("Vector.<" + className + ">"));
        objects = new vectorClass(poolsize);
    }
}
```

I tried it with both int and a custom class and it seems to be working fine.  Of course you would have to check if you actually gain any speed from this since objects is a Vector.<*> and flash might be making some implicit type checks that would negate the speed up you get from using a vector.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is interesting. I'd done some tests back in April to determine what type of object I was getting - I have a hunch that if I checked, using your code, I would find that the type was actually a generic Vector. Interesting solution, though. I may try it out, but I'm actually considering taking up Java, as it's similar in a lot of ways...but more powerful and more versatile in the job market. Additionally, I could still create games. :D

Answer (score 1):

It is good you trying to stay away from new but:

Everything I have ever read about Vector<> in actionscript says it must be strongly typed. So 
this shouldn't work.

Edit: I am saying it can't be done.
Here see if this helps.

[Is it possible to define a generic type Vector in Actionsctipt 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598371/is-it-possible-to-define-a-generic-type-vector-in-actionsctipt-3)

Comment: I'm trying to pass a type as a variable so that I can instantiate the vector with a type of my choosing, while staying away from multiple if statements, switch clauses, or multiple classes. The problem is that I can't seem to specify a type in a variable and use that variable inside the brackets.

Comment: I see what your trying to do. I am pretty sure it can't be done. I would love to be wrong though.

Comment: @ Feltope Upvote for finding that thread - I missed it. Tyler Egeto found the official bug, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dock, but try this:

```
var classType:Class = getDefinitionByName(type) as Class;
...
objects = new Vector.<classType>(poolsize);  // line 15
```

*drops the mic*

Comment: I doubt this makes a difference, I would be very interested if it does, but it is doing exactly the same thing as the original example, just moving where the Class type is declared.

Comment: Here's what's weird. I tried that, and it compiled, but a describeType on the vector revealed that it was of type Sprite. So I reverted and compiled again....and it compiled with the same problem. Tried some other stuff, wondering....and then for the hell of it decided to type it to int - it still compiled as Sprite. Restarted FlashDevelop and now it won't compile at all? Is my compiler haunted? :P

Comment: FlashDevelop doesn't have a "clean" function (sadly) so I deleted my SWF, figuring that a full recompile was necessary. Got the following error - \src\ObjPool.as(15): col: 46 Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type String.

Comment: Hey lunchmeat...that's incredibly odd. Maybe the Vector is considering "Class" as actually a class... and not the class type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point in using a Vector.<*>. Might as well go with Array.

Anyhow, I just came up with this way of dynamically create Vectors:

```
public function getCopy (ofVector:Object):Object
{
    var copy:Object = new ofVector.constructor;
   // Do whatever you like with the vector as long as you don't need to know the type

    return copy;
}
```