# As3 Vector<T> parametric TYPE

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

I have one vector instance and I'm exporting swf with Flash Player 10/10.1.

I want initialise it with a parametric type. I tried as follow:

```
var someType:Class = MyCustomClass;
var v:Vector.<someType> = new Vector.<someType>();
```

But it doesn't work!!
There is a way to do this?

I hope question is clear :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someType` is the instance of the class type; whereas Vector is a container of that type.

This should be:

```
var v:Vector.<MyCustomClass> = new Vector.<MyCustomClass>();
```

Otherwise, I've noticed Haxe would compile this as:

```
var v:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
```

Flash polymorphism is lacking, if you had class A and class B, and attempted to push them to a vector of type Class you would receive an error:

Example

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        public function test()
        {
            var v:Vector.<Class> = new Vector.<Class>();

            var a:A = new A();
            var b:B = new B();

            v.push(a);
            v.push(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert A@43a2ff1 to Class.
```

Comment: I know this. I have to mantain vector type as a parameter bacause I don't know prior of which type vector will be!

Comment: Sadly, I do not believe ActionScript is your language to handle this.  I find template / generics disappointing in ActionScript.  There are tickets logged at Adobe requesting this functionality.  Vector alone only taunts this capability...

Comment: Perhaps your custom types could extend a base class / implement interface - Vector.<IMyCustomInterface> to which you could then test with "is [type]" statements.

Comment: Thank you but I want use all types, not only mine :-(

Comment: Please vote and raise concern in the Adobe Bug and Issue Management System for ActionScript Language ASL-115 - Complete support for Generic Types / Full Generic API at https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-115

Answer (score 1):

Jason's right. You can't do this. I'm sorry. I ran into the same problem a while back.

[Dynamically instantiate a typed Vector from function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508630/677526)

Sucks, doesn't it? :-)