# Can AS3 vectors be declared with a type reference?

Tags: actionscript-3, generics, vector

Instead of this:

```
var v:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
```

is there any way to do something like this?

```
var myType:Class = String;
var v:Vector.<myType> = new Vector.<myType>();
```

Obviously that doesn't work as written, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is try [grapefrukt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954887/can-as3-vectors-be-declared-with-a-type-reference/955128#955128) and see.

However, I don't think it's possible at a bytecode level. The problem related to how generics (Vectors) are constructed. Basically the bytecode for creating an instance of Vector<> goes:

```
GenericDefinitionType (Vector) + GenericParameter (int) -> GenericType
Coerce (cast) GenericType as KnownGenericType (eg. "Vector.<int>")
```

So the issue is not in the creation, since GenericParameter is just a multiname (which can be dynamic). The issue is in the coercion to the known vector type (actually registered as "Vector.<int>" for example) since there is no known vector type.

See my post on [how Vectors work in bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553445/how-do-generics-vector-work-inside-the-avm/553451#553451) for the geeky details.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found sort of a way to create Vectors dynamically. Instead of passing the type as class you pass the whole vector as class, like:

```
public function createVector (vectorType:Object):Object
{
    return new vectorType();
}

var v:Vector.<String> = createVector(Vector.<String>);
```

Or you can copy a vector like this:

```
public function getCopy (ofVector:Object):Object
{
    var copy:Object = new ofVector.constructor;

    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, but I can't see why it shouldn't work:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("flash.display.Sprite") as Class;
var v:Vector.<ClassReference> = new Vector.<ClassReference>();
```

Comment: Huh? That does precisely the same thing as the non-working example code in my question, except with Sprite instead of String.